# Trying to count distinct records on each table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I have a query that gives me the total number of records in each table in a database:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('MyDb') + '.' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([sOBJ].schema_id)) +
'.' + QUOTENAME([sOBJ].[name]) AS [TableName], SUM([sPTN].[Rows]) AS [RowCount]
FROM [MyDB].[sys].[objects] AS [sOBJ]
INNER JOIN [sys].[partitions] AS [sPTN]
ON [sOBJ].object_id = [sPTN].object_id
WHERE  [sOBJ].[type] = 'U'
AND [sOBJ].[is_ms_shipped] = 0x0
AND [index_id] < 2 -- 0:Heap, 1:Clustered
GROUP BY [sOBJ].schema_id, [sOBJ].[name]
```

What I am trying to do is to also get a count of distinct records for each table in the database. I've tried using While loops and `CTE`s, but just can't seem to get it right. Not sure if that is the correct methodology either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: distinct on all columns for each table? if you have PK in each table then every row is distinct , I think this is not something that you can do easily , you need to know the column names that determine distinction in each table

Comment: You'd want index statistics or table stats, but I haven't seen a way to query those directly. The only surefire way would be to literally select distinct * to count the rows, and that's pretty awful.

Comment: Thank you both for your response, this is what I thought as well but wasn't sure I was correct.

Comment: `HAVING SUM([sPTN].[Rows]) = 1` ? Or replace `SUM` with `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` and use `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`?